# Laravel model field with dynamic type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In my Laravel project, I'm building a way to dynamically create questions which the users of my platform should answer. For this I have two models:

One model for the questions, containing one field (string) for the question itself and one field for what type of question it is (free text, dropdown, checkbox etc).

And then I have one model for the answers given by the users. My question is in what format I am to use for the answers, since it's different type depending on the question. My initial plan is to make it a string, and then if it's a checkbox (boolean) question I have to store it as "true" or "false", if it's a dropdown I store the index of the answer as "1", "2" etc. This would work but it doesn't feel like an elegant solution. Are there better ways to do this? What i'd really want would be some kind of field with dynamic type...

Comment: A [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna keep it simple, an `eloquent` `accessor` could solve most problems. Imagine your answer has a question related to it, something like this could solve your dynamic typing problem.

```
class Answer {
    public function getValueAttribute() {
        if ($this->question->type === 'boolean') {
            // save bool as 1 or 0, way easier imo
            return (bool) $this->answer;
        }

        if ($this->question->type === 'dropdown') {
            // asuming you can get the options
            return $this->answer->getOptions()[(int) $this->answer];
        }
    }
}
```

This is very vague or pseudo like solution, but i hope it can get you in the right path. Now you could get the dynamic type by.

```
$answer->value;
```

Comment: Yep, I thought I'd do something like that. I guess that confirms I'm thinking in the right direction. I thought maybe there would be a completely different magical way to do this (I've learned sometimes in the Laravel world there is) but this is enought for me :-)